# how to import stored procedures into HDFS

Tags: mysql, hadoop, stored-procedures, hdfs

Is there a way to import mysql stored procedure to HDFS?
I have seen an export regarding the same [link](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/SqoopUserGuide.html)

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://db.example.com/foo --call barproc \
    --export-dir /results/bar_data
```

But when I used --call along with my import statement it is not working

> sqoop-import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/storedProc --call
>   tabl_Proc --username root --password pass --target-dir
>   hdfs://:8020/procedureTest

Sample mysql Procedure

```
mysql> delimiter // 
mysql> create procedure tabl_Proc() 
    -> begin 
    -> select * from CUSTOMERS; end //
```

Is there a way to get my procedure into HDFS

Comment: You have this tagged with MySQL, SQL Server and Hadoop, are you really using all three products?

Answer (score 1):

1. This is an [open issue in apache sqoop](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-769) .
2. Although you can use [Free Form Queries](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html#_free_form_query_imports) in sqoop import, meaning
   you can write your mysql stored procedure syntax in free form query
   of sqoop import (obviously you have to alter some syntax in free
   form query)